# Resize all images to same absolute width with IM

Tags: imagemagick

I have a bunch of images of varying sizes and aspect ratios, most (but not all) in "portrait" mode. How do I scale them all to the exact same absolute width (say, 600px) and let IM use the appropriate height to keep the aspect ratio)? The doc and examples that I have seen for `-geometry` always use both width and height, unless they use relative scales, which I don't want to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - it will write the output files to a subdirectory called `results`:

```
mkdir results
magick mogrify -path results -resize 600x *.jpg
```

Omit the `magick` if using v6 or older.

Comment: *Slaps forehead* :)

Comment: I slap mine so much, I have no hair left! :-)

Comment: Neither have I :)